# How to Know from which fragment onBackPressed() was called

Tags: android, fragment, onbackpressed, fragment-backstack

In Method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
```

Is getting called whenever back is pressed in one of my Fragments.
Is there some way I can tell which fragment is the one that is active?
Or some other inforamtion inside OnBackPressed()?

Added information:
This is how I replace fragments inside the activity:
[image]
Thank you

Comment: if you add your fragment's transactions in the backstack, then you could possibly find that out

Comment: have you used backstackentry()?? When you add or replace fragment

Comment: @ArpitPatel what do you mean exactly? if you mean addToBackStack () before replace fragment - so yes